# How to use mongoDB collection output as variables in ansible

Tags: json, mongodb, variables, ansible, output

I can able to print the mongodb data using ansible. but here my requirement is to use the printed data as variables in ansible.

here is the output I'm getting ansible playbook output:

[image: ansible playbook output]

here is my ansible playbook.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars: 
    - i: "db.repo.find({ $and: [{'product': 'Admin'}, {'env':'SHK'}] }).pretty()"

  tasks:
  - name: Printing the retrieved data
    command: mongo Advantage --quiet --eval "{{i}}"
    register: temp  

  - name: Printing the retrieved data
    set_fact:
     "{{item}}"
    with_items:
      - [ "{{temp.stdout.split('\t')[0] }}", "{{temp.stdout.split('\t')[1] }}", "{{temp.stdout.split('\t')[2] }}", "{{temp.stdout.split('\t')[3] }}", "{{temp.stdout.split('\t')[4] }}", "{{temp.stdout.split('\t')[5] }}", "{{temp.stdout.split('\t')[6] }}", "{{temp.stdout.split('\t')[7] }}", "{{temp.stdout.split('\t')[8] }}", "{{temp.stdout.split('\t')[9] }}" ]


- include: /etc/ansible/roles/patchdeployment_3_11_2/tasks/applypatch/applypatch_windows_websphere.yml PR_ID={{PR_ID}} 
#- include: /etc/ansible/roles/patchdeployment_3_11_2/tasks/applypatch/applypatch_linux_websphere.yml
```

please help me on the same.

Answer (score 0):

Make mongo output pure JSON friendly by disabling all fields with custom types (like `_id`) in query.
Then use `from_json` Ansible filter to parse output.

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars: 
    qry: "db.repo.findOne({ $and: [{'product': 'Admin'}, {'env':'SHK'}] },{_id:false})"

  tasks:
    - name: Get data
      command: mongo Advantage --quiet --eval "{{qry}}"
      register: temp

    - name: Save parsed data
      set_fact:
        mongo_result: "{{ temp.stdout | from_json }}" 

    - name: Print some data
      debug:
        var: mongo_result.appName
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Konstantin suvorov. your script works for me up to single variable. but I have multiple variables in mongodb like appName, appFolder, env, product how can I mention multiple variables in script. your response will be appriciated. please help me I was working from few days on this issue but I couldn't able to fix this. please help me.

Comment: you can refer any variable like `mongo_results.appFolder`, etc.

Comment: Thanks. @Konstantin Suvorov